# Why isn't my C++/Qt program showing label object after to click on related PushButton?

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I want to design a program including a pushButton and a lineEdit object in Qt with C++ that when the pushButton is clicked, it creates a label on the program and then sets its text to the written text in the lineEdit.
As you see inside `void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()` function in the code below, I defined in my code to create an object of QLabel type and show the written text in the lineEdit but when I build and run my program, I don't see anything and it looks like the function didn't create the label. What's wrong with my code and what should I do?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QLabel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Name: ", this);
    label->setGeometry(10, 10, 150, 15);
    label->setText(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

By the way, I'm new to Qt and that's why I accept other issues in my code. Thanks for helping.

Comment: You're using QMainWindow incorrectly. Please read the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details) paying particular attention to [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget).

Comment: Do you connect the button click signal to the function? Also, all you do is create a label, you don't add it to the window.

Comment: You could create your label as part of the ui and make it hidden until the button is pressed.

Comment: `QLabel *label = new QLabel("Name: ", ui->centralWidget); label->show();`